# How to check strings for special symbols

Tags: python, pandas

I have to check each row of the table for special symbols and add a column with the number of symbols without using cycles,but i have to use regular expressions

I write a regular expression:

```
rexp = '("|#|%|\[|\])'
len(re.findall(rexp, 'asdfasf[sadfsaf%sadfad]]'))
```

And I try to solve it like this:

```
def special_symbols(x):
    if len(re.findall(rexp, x['game_description'])) >0:
        return len(re.findall(rexp, x['game_description']))
    else:
        return 0

games_df['n_special_symbols'] = games_df.apply(special_symbols, axis =1)
```

But I have an error:

> expected string or bytes-like object

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `axis=1`? and why are you applying it to the whole of the frame?

Comment: I use axis=1 that the def was applied to rows. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
games_df['n_special_symbols'] = games_df['your column with the string goes here'].apply(special_symbols)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use `apply`. It's much faster and easier to address a built-in [pandas.Series.str.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) which takes a regular expression as a parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'game_description':['one[two]three','four#five','%six%seven%','eight']})
special = '"|#|%|\[|\]'
df['n_special_symbols'] = df['game_description'].str.count(special)
```

Output:

```
  game_description  n_special_symbols
0    one[two]three                  2
1        four#five                  1
2      %six%seven%                  3
3            eight                  0
```